# Legends in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying plot this data, and the line graph is correct, but I can't make the legend show up. Any thoughts?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time_months, size=I(1))) +geom_line(aes(y=monthly_net_revenue, color=I("blue"))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=cumsum(discounted_monthly_net_revenue), color=I("purple"))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=monthly_expenses, color=I("red"))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=cumsum(monthly_revenue), color=I("green")))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Right now we can't see what your plot looks like

Answer (score 2):

This will probably work for you

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time_months, size=I(1))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=monthly_net_revenue, color="blue")) +
    geom_line(aes(y=cumsum(discounted_monthly_net_revenue), color="purple")) +
    geom_line(aes(y=monthly_expenses, color="red")) +
    geom_line(aes(y=cumsum(monthly_revenue), color="green")) + 
    scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")
```

The `scale_color_identity()` uses the values you pass to `color=` directly as the color rather than treating them like a group name. You don't need `I()` with this method.

Comment: Not sure if OP will need it but perhaps you could add that the argument `guide = "legend"` is needed to show the legend.

Comment: @markus Where do you suggest putting that parameter? Won't the guide automatically show up if done like this?

Comment: The default is `guide = "none"` in `scale_color_identity()` - which makes totally sense but OP stated that they can't make the legend show up. That's why I commented.

Comment: @markus Ahh. I see what you are saying. Yes. Forgot that detail. It's much easier to test when sample data is included!