Custom GGPlot Legend
Here is some simple "R" code I wrote:
library(ggplot2)

Year <- seq(from = 2010, to = 2024, by = 1)
IndoorCount <- round(runif(length(Year), 0, 50))
OutdoorCount <- round(runif(length(Year), 0, 50))
MyData <- data.frame(Year, IndoorCount, OutdoorCount)

# head(MyData)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794515/legends-in-ggplot

MyPlot <-
  ggplot(MyData, aes(x = Year)) +
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_x_continuous("Year", labels = MyData$Year, breaks = MyData$Year) +
  scale_y_continuous("Ride Count") +
  geom_line(aes(y = IndoorCount, color="red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = OutdoorCount, color="green")) +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")

It produces this graph:

The legend shows:
Colour

Green
Red

How can I generate a legend that displays:
Location

Indoor (in Red)
Outdoor (in Green)

Should be simple, right?
Do I have to create a Location column in my data.frame with values ('Indoor'/'Outdoor')?
That would be an over complicated way of doing this, in my opinion.
Thank you for all pointers/advice!
Richard

The following method is not too overly complicated. You just need to tidy the data. It simplifies the ggplot code quite substantially.
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(MyData, -Year, names_to="Location", values_to="Ride Count") |>
  mutate(Location=sub('Count', '', Location)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y=`Ride Count`, col=Location)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=MyData$Year) +
  theme_minimal()



set.seed(123)

Year <- seq(from = 2010, to = 2024, by = 1)
IndoorCount <- round(runif(length(Year), 0, 50))
OutdoorCount <- round(runif(length(Year), 0, 50))
MyData <- data.frame(Year, IndoorCount, OutdoorCount)


I apologize, I forgot to thank you! Thank you very much Edward!!!

Just use the name, breaks, and labels arguments of scale_color_identity:
MyPlot <-
  ggplot(MyData, aes(x = Year)) +
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_x_continuous("Year", labels = MyData$Year, breaks = MyData$Year) +
  scale_y_continuous("Ride Count") +
  geom_line(aes(y = IndoorCount, color="red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = OutdoorCount, color="green")) +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = "legend",
    name = "Location",
    breaks = c("red", "green"),
    labels = c("Indoor", "Outdoor")
  )

No additional column required!


I apologize, I forgot to thank you! Thank you very much Jigsaw!!!
